# Item variants in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the best way to use item variants in elasticsearch and retrieving only 1 item of the variant group?

For example, let's say I have the following items:

```js
[{
    "sku": "abc-123",
    "group": "abc",
    "color": "red",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "sku": "def-123",
    "group": "def",
    "color": "red",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "sku": "abc-456",
    "group": "abc",
    "color": "black",
    "price": 20
  }
]
```

The first item and the last one are in the same group, so I want only to return one of them if I query for items below the price of 20 (for example), but with the best hit score.

Feel free to suggest documents design and queries accordingly.

Comment: Please share your mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mapping is of [Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), then you can use this to retrieve them.

```
GET index/type/_search
{
  "size": 2000, 
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "childs",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "childs.group.keyword": "abc"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": {} 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```